# Create Data Frame and Populate It R

Tags: r

How do I create a fixed size data frame of size `[40 2]`, declare the first column with unique strings, and populate the other with specific values?  Again, I want the first column to be the list of strings; I don't
want a row of headers.

(Someone please give me some pointers. I haven't program in R for a while and my R skills are terrible to
begin with.)

Comment: What strings and values do you want in your data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

```
# sequential strings
library(stringr)
df.1 <- data.frame(id=paste0("X",str_pad(1:40,2,"left","0")),value=NA)
head(df.1)
#    id value
# 1 X01    NA
# 2 X02    NA
# 3 X03    NA
# 4 X04    NA
# 5 X05    NA
# 6 X06    NA
```

Second Approach:

```
# random strings
rstr <- function(n,k){
  sapply(1:n,function(i){do.call(paste0,as.list(sample(letters,k,replace=T)))})
}
set.seed(1)
df.2 <- data.frame(id=rstr(40,5),value=NA)
head(df.2)
#      id value
# 1 gjoxf    NA
# 2 xyrqb    NA
# 3 ferju    NA
# 4 mszju    NA
# 5 yfqdg    NA
# 6 kajwi    NA
```

The function `rstr(n,k)` produces a vector of length n with each element being a string of random characters of length k. `rstr(...)` does not guarantee that all strings are unique, but the probability of duplication is `O(n/26^k)`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the data.frame and define it's columns with the values

The reciclying rule, repeats the strings to match the 40 rows defined by the second column

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("unique_string 1", "unique_string 2"), y = rpois(40, 2))

# Change column names
names(df) <- c("string_col", "num_col")
```

Comment: `sample(letters, 40, replace = TRUE)` doesn't generate 40 unique strings.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way of creating dataframes in R extremely productive and easy,
Create a raw array of values , then convert into matrix of required dimenions and finally name the columns and rows

```
dataframe.values = c(value1, value2,.......)
dataframe = matrix(dataframe.values,nrow=number of rows ,byrow = T)
colnames(dataframe) = c("column1","column2",........)
row.names(dataframe) = c("row1", "row2",............)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exampledf <- data.frame(columnofstrings=c("a string", "another", "yetanother"), 
                        columnofvalues=c(2,3,5) )
```

gives

```
> exampledf
  columnofstrings columnofvalues
1        a string              2
2         another              3
3      yetanother              5
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to populate the right side yet. I just want a data frame with the first column of names.